# Google Reverse Geocoding API doesn't work on mobile internet

Tags: geocoding, geolocation, jquery, reverse-geocoding, ajax

I was able to get Google Geolocations and Geocoder API to work via desktop and on my phone when its connected to wifi, but when I disconnect from the wifi, geocoder doesn't display the results.

just to explain a bit more about what my code does, i use the geolocation API to get lat/long values and then i use that output that is stored in a variable and i use it to get the city information using the reverse geocoding google API.

my code below is as follows:

```
jQuery(function() {
      var GOOGLE_API_KEY = 'MY_KEY_HERE';
     var outlatlong = null;
      jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key='+GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        data: JSON.stringify({ "considerIp": "true" }),
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function(data) {
            
    outlatlong = [data.location.lat, data.location.lng].join(', ');
            
         
          if(data.location) {
            var out = [data.location.lat, data.location.lng].join(', ');
            jQuery('#gresponse').html(out);
           
    var urlTwo = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+out+"&key=MY_KEY_HERE";
    jQuery.get(urlTwo).success(function(data) {
       var loc1 = data.results[0];
       var county, city;
         jQuery.each(loc1, function(k1,v1) {
            if (k1 == "address_components") {
               for (var i = 0; i < v1.length; i++) {
                  for (k2 in v1[i]) {
                     if (k2 == "types") {
                        var types = v1[i][k2];
                        if (types[0] =="sublocality_level_1") {
                            county = v1[i].long_name;
                            //alert ("county: " + county);
                        } 
                        if (types[0] =="locality") {
                           city = v1[i].long_name;
                           alert ("city: " + city);
                       } 
                     }
                  }          
               }
            }

         });
         jQuery('#lattie').html(city); 
        
        
    });
              
          } else {
            jQuery('#lattie').html('didnt work');
          }
        },
        error: function(e) {
          console.log('error!', JSON.parse(e.responseText));
        }
      });
        return outlatlong
    });
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using the webservice (as opposed to the Google Maps Javascript API v3)?  Do you get any errors reported by the Reverse Geocoder request?  Is your key restricted at all?

Comment: @geocodezip I get no errors, but it just shows as undefined. I've been doing more testing  and reading from what gather since its i am not asking for permissions, google doesnt place you anywhere if you are on your phone. If its on desktop it just puts you at the closets node.

Comment: @geocodezip yes my key is restricted i can have it unrestricted if you would like. Those are the only way ive found that worked for me. I found another way but it does ask for permission (which is the right thing to do but my client just wants to have it passive).

Comment: What "shows as undefined"? Can you add error handling to the jQuery requests and check for error responses?  If your key is restricted, is it the restriction correct for your phone?

Comment: @geocodezip well i figured out why. its because since i am not asking for permission to get an exact location, google just shows it as undefined.